# SQL Date and TIme

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date, to-char

I need to take the list of students with Application acceptance Date & time in University database. The report is sent on 6 PM evening to the management but the management can run it on 7 PM 8 PM or any time within the night. The application should be just 2 days ahead to the report running date.

ORACLE: I have created a query but that will give the application of entire 24 hours of a day. The problem with this query is when management runs a query on 6 PM and 8 PM , and any students are accepted in between this time. The result will be different.

```
select 
    to_char(application_accepted_date, 'DD-MON-RR:HH24:MI:SS')
from 
    tbl_application_accepted_date
where 
    to_date(application_accepted_date, 'DD-MON-rr:HH24:MI:SS') = 
    to_date(trunc(sysdate-2), 'DD-MON-rr:HH24:MI:SS')
```

;

If any application is accepted between 6 ahead I need the list in next days report. Means, I should have the list of accepted students from 6PM onwards of previous day to 5:59 application day. 
    [image: I am getting application accepted after 6 PM, which I don't need in todays report, I should get this on next day report. The report is run on 4th OCT 2018]

I am getting application accepted after 6 PM, which I don't need in todays report, I should get this on next day report. The report is run on 4th OCT 2018

Comment: `to_date(trunc(sysdate-2), 'DD-MON-rr:HH24:MI:SS')` is useless, just write `trunc(sysdate-2)` - it is pointless to cast a `DATE` value into a `DATE` value

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to cut off at 6pm, then just add 18/24 (18 hours) to the truncated date. You are also doing a lot of unnecessary casting. As long as `application_accepted_date` is a date field, then you can just compare it as a date.

```
select to_char(application_accepted_date, 'DD-MON-RR:HH24:MI:SS')
from tbl_application_accepted_date
where application_accepted_date >= trunc(sysdate-3)+18/24
  and application_accepted_date <  trunc(sysdate-2)+18/24
```

This will give you any applications starting at 6pm 3 days ago until just before 6pm 2 days ago.

**EDIT**: You could also do this with interval literals if you want. Same query as above, but more explicit in your intentions.

```
select to_char(application_accepted_date, 'DD-MON-RR:HH24:MI:SS')
    from tbl_application_accepted_date
    where application_accepted_date >= trunc(sysdate-3) + interval '18' hour
      and application_accepted_date <  trunc(sysdate-2) + interval '18' hour
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that application_accepted_date is a DATE datatype in your data model, try this:

```
select 
    to_char(application_accepted_date, 'DD-MON-RR:HH24:MI:SS')
from 
    tbl_application_accepted_date
    WHERE  application_accepted_date BETWEEN to_date(To_char(Trunc(SYSDATE - 1),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ||'18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS) and to_date(to_char(trunc(sysdate),'yyyy-mm-dd')||'17:59:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS)
```

That should always return data from 6:00pm yesterday to 5:59:59pm today.